# How to set different warning levels for different files?

Tags: cmake, compiler-warnings, warning-level

While I can set different warning levels depending on the compiler, e.g.:

```
if(MSVC)
  target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE /W4 /WX)
else()
  target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror)
endif()
```

I cannot set them on a file by file basis.

In the same directory, I have a set of files whose names are in the `${SRC_WARN}` CMake variable, which need a different warning level compared to the others.

Is there a way to specify such a condition with `target_compile_options`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set compile options ([`COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html)) for a single file (or group of files) using [`set_source_files_properties()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html#command:set_source_files_properties). You can change the `COMPILE_OPTIONS` for your `${SRC_WARN}` source files by adding to your existing CMake code:

```
if(MSVC)
  target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE /W4 /WX)
  # Change these files to have warning level 2.
  set_source_files_properties(${SRC_WARN} PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS /W2)
else()
  target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror)
  # Change these files to inhibit all warnings.
  set_source_files_properties(${SRC_WARN} PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS -w)
endif()
```

Comment: Should/can I use the PRIVATE token to specify that this is a local property?

Comment: Is it `COMPILE_OPTIONS` or `COMPILE_FLAGS`?

Comment: You can't use the visibility qualifiers like `PUBLIC` or `PRIVATE` with the `set_source_file_properties()` command. These properties will only be applied to those source files, and will only be visible to targets added in the same CMakeLists.txt file. And based on the documentation, you should use the newer `COMPILE_OPTIONS`; the `COMPILE_FLAGS` property is the old property.